# iOS UIImageView not refreshing automatically

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uikit, ios9

I'm learning iOS programming by following [this wonderful tutorial](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/developing-ios-8-apps-using-swift-interaction-with-multiple-views/), except I'm targeting iOS 9 and make some small modifications.

In the tableView() function below, I can get thumbnail image downloaded and my handlers invoked, as evident from the console print out of the two logging lines. However, when the app is running (in simulator), I have to click on each table cell to get the image to show up. I tried to see if there is a `refresh()` or something like that in the `UIImageView` or the table cell, but found nothing.

How to make the image show up immediately as the data is received?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier)!
    let album = self.albums[indexPath.row]

    // ... setting up other cell's data, see the tutorial link

    // Start by setting the cell's image to a static file
    // Without this, we will end up without an image view!
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "Blank52")

    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: thumbnailURL)
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("received thumbnail \(thumbnailURLString)") // reached
        if error == nil {
            // Convert the downloaded data in to a UIImage object
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            // Update the cell
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                print("...dispatched thumbnail image for \(thumbnailURLString)") // reached
                if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                    cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
                }
            })
        }
    }).resume()

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a work around. If I also update the text slight, the image shows up right the way without clicking on the table view cell.

```
cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
cellToUpdate.textLabel?.text = "\(album.title) " // a space is added to the end to make a difference and force the cell to be updated
```

Sounds like a bug in `UITableViewCell` (or the simulator? haven't tried on a real device) to me.

Answer (score 2):

This part doesn't make sense:

```
if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
```

This seems to be creating an infinite loop. Every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will cause *another* call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

I think you just meant:

```
cell.imageView?.image = image
```

You already know the cell. You just created it before calling this block. You don't need to look it up again.

Answer (score 0):

Why u just try without dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) part.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            print("...dispatched thumbnail image for \(thumbnailURLString)") // reached
            if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
                cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
            }
        })
```

to

```
cell.imageView?.image = image
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to cast the cell when you get the cell you try to update.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        print("...dispatched thumbnail image for \(thumbnailURLString)") // reached
        if let cellToUpdate = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UITableViewCell {
            cellToUpdate.imageView?.image = image
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** Just put the following piece of code in the **cellForRowAt** delegate method after setting the image.

```
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
           tableView.beginUpdates()
           tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    // Full Method
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PhotoCell", for: indexPath) as? PhotoCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
                let model = self.arrPhotos?[indexPath.row]
// Below method download image from url using asycn
                SwiftHelper.downloadImageFrom(strUrl: model?.url ?? "") {[weak self] (img) in
                    guard let _ = self, let image = img else { return }
                    print("ImgDownloaded")
                    cell.imgView.image = image
                   // cell.layoutIfNeeded()
                    UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                       tableView.beginUpdates()
                       tableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                }
                return cell
            }
```

To do animation on image you can remove performWithoutAnimation block.